# Customize auto-completion (more) in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, auto-completion

So I just found "User > Customize Completion" in texmaker and it seemed great. Quite soon I run into the problem with defining macros that span several lines.

I am able to get:

```
\begin{figure}[•] \centering \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{•}

\end{figure}
```

but I would like:

```
\begin{figure}[•]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{•}
\end{figure}
```

And maybe even an indent within the figure environment. As a frequent user of Overleaf I have grown used to being able of having this kind of auto-completion. Is it possible to configure?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at least 10 of them: User -> User tags -> Edit user tags.

If I add the following to one of the tags:

```
\begin{figure}[@]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{@}
\end{figure}
```

and hit the corresponding keyboard shortcut in a document, I get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also customize tags under `Structure -> User`. Here, you can define as many tags as you want (so no restriction from number of available FX keys) with formatting. The tag is triggered by writing `:(tag)` and pressing the right arrow key in the editor.

I use this for all my more advanced autocompletion or to quickly access frequently used commands that are similar in name to others (e.g. `\text{}` or `\cite{}`, where I can circumvent that pesky `\citep{}`).

EDIT:
On Andrew Swann's suggestion here are some screenshots showing the process.

Location of `Structure -> User`:

[image]

Add new tag (here I modify my own to input `\text{}`, but the idea is the same):

[image]

Result in editor:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Could you add some screenshots showing how to use this?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and the edit! I've added them to the post.